# convert struct to cell array indexes Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cells, cell-array

How to convert struct to cell array indexes, I have struct which I want to convert to the cell array indexes with respect to to `data` & `label`. Or possibly direct cell arrays according to label and data to avoid `struct` usage.

**My Code:**

```
for ii = 1:13
    for jj = 1:numel(obj.R)
        %R calc operatioiins
    end
    R=R(~cellfun('isempty',R)) ;
    TData(ii).data=R;
    TData(ii).label=cellfun(@(x) ['T' num2str(ii)] , num2cell(1:length(R))', 'UniformOutput', false);

end
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  TData(1).data

ans = 

    [10x3 double]
    [10x3 double]
    [10x3 double]
    [10x3 double]
    [10x3 double]
    [10x3 double]
    [10x3 double]

>> TData(1).label

ans = 

    'T1'
    'T1'
    'T1'
    'T1'
    'T1'
    'T1'
    'T1'
```

**EDIT 1:**

Possibly change the following:
**Actual Output:**

```
[10x3 double]
[10x3 double]
[ 8x3 double]
[10x3 double]
[10x3 double]
[10x3 double]
[10x3 double]
'T1'         
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
'T2'         
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
[ 5x3 double]
'T3'
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[10x3 double] 'T1' 
[10x3 double] 'T1' 
[ 8x3 double] 'T1' 
[10x3 double] 'T1' 
[10x3 double] 'T1' 
[10x3 double] 'T1' 
[10x3 double] 'T1'
```

Comment: Did you look at `struct2cell`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html

Comment: @rayryeng yeah .. it gives the same output like EDIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but try adding this to the end of your for-loop:

```
TDataCellArray{ii} = {{TData(ii).data}, {TData(ii).label}}
```